# How to create a Download link for a program

Tags: java

So I've recently created a java-based translator app using Microsoft's Translator API in NetBeans. What I want to do now is make my application shareable by creating a download link to it as a desktop application. The problem is that I have no idea how to do that, and I can't seem to find any helpful guides on how to do this online. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

> Run > Build Project

or

> press F11

You should get a .jar file that you can upload to for example Google Drive, there you can get a download link for your file.

Users need to install java runtime in order to run your application.

Comment: Please let me know if this helped!